How to fix CORS policy in ASP.NET with React
When calling my API with Postman it works, however, with my website it doesn't. I got the console error below when I tried:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5243' from origin
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an
asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel
closed before a response was received

I modified the program.cs as explained in this post but didn't work.
Below are the program.cs and memberadd.jsx code:
//Program.cs:

var policyName = "AllowLocalhost3000"; //
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add CORS policy to allow requests from 'http://localhost:3000'

builder.Services.AddCors(options => 
{ 
    options.AddPolicy(name: policyName, 
        policyBuilder => 
        { 
            policyBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000") 
                         .AllowAnyHeader()  
                         .AllowAnyMethod()  
                         .AllowCredentials() 
                         .WithExposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
                         .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true); 
        }); 
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer(); 
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(policyName);

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) 
{ 
    app.UseSwagger(); 
    app.UseSwaggerUI(); 
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


//MemberAdd.jsx:

try { 
    const response = await axios.post( 
        `http://localhost:5243/MemberFirstName=${encodeURIComponent(member.firstName)}&LastName=${encodeURIComponent(member.lastName)}&DOB=${encodeURIComponent(member.dob)}&email=${encodeURIComponent(member.email)}`
);

if (response.status === 200) {
    alert("Member Added!");
    clearForm();
  } else {
    alert("Failed to add member.");
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error adding member: ", error);
  alert("An error occurred while adding the member.");
}


Did you add the following attribute to your controller method? [EnableCors("AllowLocalhost3000")]

Also your axios.post call is incorrect. You either forgot the ? in front of your query parameters, which wouldn't make sense because you'd be posting to the website root. Or you forgot your correct full path

This question has been asked tens of thousands of times.  Why did you think that asking it again was a good idea?  You could have just read the existing answer.

Your example works perfectly fine. Make sure you are using correct port of your React application.

Hi Eddie, please check my solution below and tell me if it works for you. If still facing same issue, we can try to enable cors logging feature to check what happened.

Because in a few cases, exceptions occur before or after the CORS middleware, and sometimes CORS error messages are reported incorrectly.

.WithExposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000") is used to expose certain response headers to the client, but it's not needed for setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin
You should try to pass the data as a JSON object instead of query parameters for security reasons at most, but also to be more aligned with REST principles.
one last thing, make sure the recipient method in the controller is decorated with [HttpPost]

UPDATE
Since you are using UseHttpsRedirection, and why it is still using http://localhost:5243 endpoint in cors error message.
So please follow my suggestions below to check if it can fix the issue.
1. Use https endpoint in your front-end.
try { 
    const response = await axios.post( 
        `https://localhost:port/MemberFirstName=${encodeURIComponent(member.firstName)}&LastName=${encodeURIComponent(member.lastName)}&DOB=${encodeURIComponent(member.dob)}&email=${encodeURIComponent(member.email)}`
);

2. Use below cors setting.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: policyName,
        policyBuilder =>
        {
            policyBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                         .AllowAnyHeader()
                         .AllowAnyMethod()
                         .WithExposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
                         .AllowCredentials();
        });
});

3. Change the middleware order like below.
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors(policyName);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

The cors issue should be fixed by applying the changes above.
PREVIOUS
You can't use WithOrigins and SetIsOriginAllowed together.
The following code is an example of a correct CORS setup.
1. Allow All.
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyMethod()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials();
}));

2. Allow specific Origin.
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
{
    policy
        .WithOrigins("Your A site") 
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials();
}));

Here is related link: SignalR Cross Domain
